# Deep copy Array where Element is Optional of custom class

Tags: arrays, swift, copy, swift4

First of all: I cannot use structs in my scenario. I know structs are "pass-by-value" by default. But i really need the "pass-by-reference" semantic of a class object in my case.

Like the title says, i am trying to deep copy an Array, which is holding optional objects of a custom class.

For the deep copy of a custom class object i implemented the following protocol:

```
protocol Copyable {
    init(instance: Self)
}

extension Copyable {
    func copy() -> Self {
        return Self.init(instance: self)
    }
}
```

Now i also have Arrays of custom class objects which need to be deep copied. To achieve this i wrote an extension for `Array` where Element is `Copyable`, which looks like this and is working:

```
extension Array where Element: Copyable {
    func clone() -> Array {
        var copiedArray = Array<Element>()
        for element in self {
            copiedArray.append(element.copy())
        }
        return copiedArray
    }
}
```

Let's say i have 2 custom classes. The first one is already conforming to `Copyable` and looks like this:

```
class MySimpleObject: Copyable {

    let myString: String

    init() {
        self.myString = ""
    }

    required init(instance: MySimpleObject) {
        self.myString = instance.myString
    }
}
```

Now my second custom class is holding two Arrays of `MySimpleObject` (1 Array where the element is `MySimpleObject` is non-optional and 1 where the element `MySimpleObject` is optional. This class looks like this:

```
class MyObject {

    var myArray = [MySimpleObject]()
    var myArrayWithOptionals = [MySimpleObject?]()
}
```

Now i want `MyObject` conform to `Copyable` and this is the part that confuses me. First i tried like this (but this gives me an error like shown in the comment:

```
class MyObject: Copyable {

    var myArray = [MySimpleObject]()
    var myArrayWithOptionals = [MySimpleObject?]()

    required init(instance: MyObject) {
        self.myArray = instance.myArray.clone()
        self.myArrayWithOptionals = instance.myArrayWithOptionals.clone()       // Type 'MySimpleObject?' does not conform to protocol 'Copyable'
    }
}
```

This error makes sense to me. Since `MySimpleObject?` is not equal `MySimpleObject`.

My Second try was then to write another extension to Array, but i am not sure how to do this in the correct way:

```
extension Array where Element == Optional<Copyable> {
    func cloneOptional() -> Array {
        var copiedArray = Array<Element>()
        for element in self {
            copiedArray.append(element?.copy())
        }
        return copiedArray
    }
}
```

`MyObject` looks like this then: But i also get an error (again shown in the comment)

```
class MyObject: Copyable {

    var myArray = [MySimpleObject]()
    var myArrayWithOptionals = [MySimpleObject?]()

    required init(instance: MyObject) {
        self.myArray = instance.myArray.clone()
        self.myArrayWithOptionals = instance.myArrayWithOptionals.cloneOptional()   // '[MySimpleObject?]' is not convertible to 'Array<Optional<Copyable>>'
    }
}
```

Can anyone hint me to the direction i need? How would we implement this in the correct way?

If you need more information in any way let me know in the comments.

Best Regards,

Teetz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you have bit of incorrect assumption for array extension of Optional Elements. You are calling `copy` on optional which you have not declared. Just make sure that `Optional` also conform to `Copyable` and it should work fine with `clone` on optional array.

```
extension Optional: Copyable where Wrapped: Copyable {
    init(instance: Optional<Wrapped>) {
        if let instance = instance {
            self = Optional(instance.copy())
        } else {
            self = nil
        }
    }
}
```

Altogether, your code would look something like this,

```
protocol Copyable {
    init(instance: Self)
}

extension Copyable {
    func copy() -> Self {
        return Self.init(instance: self)
    }
}

extension Optional: Copyable where Wrapped: Copyable {
    init(instance: Optional<Wrapped>) {
        if let instance = instance {
            self = Optional(instance.copy())
        } else {
            self = nil
        }
    }
}

extension Array where Element: Copyable {
    func clone() -> [Element] {
        var copiedArray = [Element]()
        for element in self {
            copiedArray.append(element.copy())
        }
        return copiedArray
    }
}

class MySimpleObject: Copyable {

    let myString: String

    init() {
        self.myString = ""
    }

    required init(instance: MySimpleObject) {
        self.myString = instance.myString
    }
}

class MyObject: Copyable {

    var myArray = [MySimpleObject]()
    var myArrayWithOptionals = [MySimpleObject?]()

    required init(instance: MyObject) {
        self.myArray = instance.myArray.clone()
        self.myArrayWithOptionals = instance.myArrayWithOptionals.clone()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Sandeep. This is exactly what i needed. Working like a charm!